OneSignal playerId sometimes for some users is empty
playerId is empty for some users when i retrieve it with
   OneSignal.getUser().getPushSubscription().getId()

to send it to my backend i also tried to get it after X minutes after launching the application
I use the latest version
   implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[5.0.0, 5.99.99]'

I initialize OneSignal like this :
    OneSignal.initWithContext(this);
    String ONESIGNAL_APP_ID = "XXXXXX";
    OneSignal.initWithContext(this, ONESIGNAL_APP_ID);

And later when trying to get the playerId :
OneSignal.getUser().getPushSubscription().getId()
it's empty for some users
the problem is also reproduced when notification for the application first is disabled and when notification become enabled, OneSignal.getUser().getPushSubscription().getId() return always empty
i try using OneSignal.getUser().getPushSubscription().optIn(); and that change nothing to the problem
Any help will be apprecied

I didn't have that problem before and I'm starting to have it. Maybe having [5.0.0, 5.99.99] is not such a good idea, better to have a fix version that works and test the updates

I've uninstalled and installed the app again and then I got again the onesignal id as usual.
